# jQuery deletion of div childrens except one

Tags: jquery

How can I delete everything inside `main` except the `ul` element?

```
<div id="main">
 <div id="a">
  <div id="b">
    <div id="c"></div>
    <div id="d"></div>
    <div id="e">
      <ul></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the desired outcome is `<div id="main"><ul></ul></div>` and you want to keep all `<ul>`s (or if there's only one):

```
$( '#main' ).html( $( '#main ul' ) );​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pEvNt/

Doing `$( '#main' ).not( 'ul' ).remove()` would not work because it would remove the ul's parents and the ul with them (see http://jsfiddle.net/h67Ge/).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('#main').children().not('ul').remove();
```

Comment: @JamesAllardice True, I am trying a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Could do this

```js
  $('#main ul').detach().prependTo('#main').siblings().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul", "#main").appendTo($("#main")).siblings().remove();
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/AHHHB/)